# How to make some words of a dynamic string clickable in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON response where i am getting some questions. Now after getting those questions i want to split them into words and match those words with another JSON response and on match i want to highlight those words and make them clickable so i can show a pop up which contains that word's translation which is present in my 2nd response. At the last i want to show both matched and unmatched words together just like it was a question before but with clickable words.

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AndcN.jpg)

this is my first json

```
"status": "true",
"message": "message",
"demo": [
    {
        "qtnNumber": 1,
        "qtnItalian": "Il segnale raffigurato preannuncia un tratto di strada in cui è consentita la manovra di retromarcia",
        "qtnCategory": "SEGNALEI VERTICALI DI PERICOLO",
        "qtnType": true
    },
    {
        "qtnNumber": 2,
        "qtnItalian": "Il segnale strada in cui è consentita la manovra di retromarcia",
        "qtnCategory": "SEGNALEI VERTICALI DI PERICOLO",
        "qtnType": true
    },
```

this is my second json

```
{
"status": "true",
"message": "Vocabulary",
"vocabulary": [
    {
        "id": 3406,
        "italian": "a condizione ",
        "punajbi": "ਹਾਲਾਤ ਕੰਡੀਸ਼ਨ",
        "english": "condition",
        "number": null,
        "punjabiEnglish": "halat",
    },
    {
        "id": 3407,
        "italian": "a raso",
        "punajbi": "ਪਲੇਨ            ਇਸ ਦਾ ਬੁੱਕ ਵਿੱਚ ਪੂਰਾ ਲਫ਼ਜ਼ ਹੇ incrocio a raso => ਇਸ ਦਾ ਮਤਲਬ ਪਲੇਨ ਚੌਕ ਇੱਕੋ ਲੈਵਲ ਤੇ ਬਣਿਆ ਹੋਇਆ ਚੌਕ",
        "english": "plane",
        "number": "ikO LEVEL DA CHONK",
        "punjabiEnglish": null,

    },
    {
        "id": 3408,
        "italian": "accesso",
        "punajbi": "ਦਾਖਿਲ",
        "english": "Entry",
        "number": null,
        "punjabiEnglish": "Dakhil",
    }
```

now from first json after splitting each question into words i want to match those words with my 2nd json 'italian' field and if matched i want to highlight those words

Comment: check `RichText` or `Text.rich` widgets - they both use `TextSpan`s that can be configured with `recognizer` property

Comment: Check this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify. hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: i have updated my question please see and give me some solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine RichText with [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify):

```
RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'This is ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Linkify(
              onOpen: (link) => print("Clicked ${link.url}!"),
              text: "Made by https://cretezy.com",
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RichText` widget, with a combination of [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and  [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: i have updated my question , please see and give some solution